# Automatically rotate mongo logs in mongod.conf file

Tags: mongodb

cureetly we are not having log rotater in my mongod.conf file.my version is mongodb3.4.3  how can i give log rotater in my mongod.conf file please check my conf file and give me suggestion where to add the log rotator in my conf fileand what to add[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using *nix system, you have few choices. You can use logrotate service and send SIGUSR1 signal to mongod/mongos process. Or you can change your config `systemLog.logRotate: rename` and again send SIGUSR1.

To rotate log you can give command `db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )` too.

How you do it on the windows side, that I don't know.

Comment: we are using centos7 and we have 4 shard cluster of each in each replicatset consits of (primary+secondary+arbiter ) and config server(primary+2secondaries) and mongos is in windows instance so i need to execute in all instances or can i run it in mongos

Comment: Yes.. All Linux mongod instance logs you can handle with my answer. Those windows mongos must use some other method, but I guess that google can answer to that question. I guess that only working solution is that adminCommand with rename.

Comment: In every mongod instance i should run the db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )  is it correct also in arblter also

Comment: Yes, you can rotate arbiter log file with `db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) ` too

Comment: /var/log/mongodb/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 5
    compress
    dateext
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}    can i add this script in all mongod instances

Comment: Yes, looks fine. As long as log and lock are in those locations.

Comment: while runnig this command db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) i am not finding any log rotation there is only one file with mongod.log my log file  path is /var/log/monogdb/mongod.log

Comment: Did you get OK result from the command `iot:PRIMARY> db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
`

Comment: i have got "ok" : 1 but while checking the path there is only one log file

Comment: You must have (in config file) `logRotate: rename` at section `systemLog`. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/logRotate/

Comment: i must  give bellow systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
 logRotate: rename(in rename should i give any name)

Comment: When you have set `logRotate: rename`, and you use `SIGUSR1` or `db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ` you don't need to give any name. Log is automatically renamed to `mongod.log.2017-12-11T13-51-36` format. If you use logrotate, then your logs can be gziped automatically.

Comment: For secondaries and arbiter also i need to add the configuration file in both and execute the command in primarty or at their respecttive iot:Secondary> or enough at  iot:PRIMARY> db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) { "ok" : 1 } but in secondaries and arbiter there are no permission for this because i have give mongokey file

Comment: Rotate is done only at node where you give command. Command can be given at SECONDARY too. `iot:SECONDARY> db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
`.. And it works same way at ARBITER. So, if you want to do that logrotate directly from Linux command line (crontab) `mongo --eval='db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 })'`

Comment: last question we have 3 config servers 1 primary and 2 secondaries same in config file we should give logRotate: rename and configReplSet:PRIMARY> db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) { "ok" : 1 } configReplSet:SECONDARY>db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) { "ok" : 1 }

Comment: Yes, just right. At every server individually. After that.. Don't forget to select my answer as "right answer" here.. ;-)

Comment: Don't forget to select my answer as "right answer" here.. ;-)   my doubt is should tick the mark to green  I will surely tick it thanks for your great support

Comment: While applying logRotate: rename in conf file and applying db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 }  logs are rotationg but  logs are not gziped automatically.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I wrote earlier, if you use logrotate program, then you can have those logs compressed automatically.

Comment: I have applied but logs are not in zip format can you give me logrotate program

Comment: You need to install it, if it is not installed already. `sudo apt install logrotate` and then create config file to `sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/mongodb-server` with content of `/var/log/mongodb/*.log {
       weekly
       rotate 10
       copytruncate
       delaycompress
       compress
       notifempty
       missingok
}
` look other files at same directory as example...

Comment: In Arbiter i am unable to execute this command db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) can you give solution to this its not authenticating to work with this command in arbiter